# Fill MKOverlay with specific color and blending mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, quartz-core, mkoverlay

I need to fill MKOverlay with specific color and kCGBlendModeMultiply blending mode. I've implemented MKOverlayRenderer subclass as follows:

```
@interface MapDimOverlayRenderer : MKOverlayRenderer

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *overlayColor;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CGFloat overlayAlpha;

@end

@implementation MapDimOverlayRenderer

- (instancetype)initWithOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay {
    self = [super initWithOverlay:overlay];
    if (self) {
        self.overlayAlpha = 0.9;
        self.overlayColor = [UIColor hx_colorWithHexString:@"2C3239" alpha:self.overlayAlpha];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context {
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeMultiply);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, self.overlayColor.CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, [self rectForMapRect:MKMapRectWorld]);
}

@end
```

The problem is CGContextSetBlendMode doesn't affect to result. I tried to set different modes. The result is always the same as default (kCGBlendModeNormal).